# How should I degitize new fonts that is improperly written in a paper

Tags: fonts, font-design

What should I do with New Fonts that is written with pencil? Yes, it should be written with a..
I have written alphabet font but I don't know what to do with it further even if it is for sale. What should I do now, can anyone help me?
In other words, what are the tools to convert it to digital format?

Thank you.

Comment: The first step would be to digitize it.

Comment: Do you mean [*'Pencil'*](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) the sketching software? Or with a pencil?

Comment: Hi S Hauzel Sailo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should do:

1. Scan your work, one glyph per file - *from here on the instructions are for each glyph separately.*

**Very important for making fonts - ach glyph is a file of it's own**

2. Open them in illustrator and convert your glyph to an svg, either by using live trace or tracing it manually (recommended)

Notice that the glyphs **must be a shape, not a stroke** - otherwise the font will interpret the stroke as whatever fills it:

[image]

3. Export each glyph as a separate svg - I recommend naming it as the glypoh it will end up being (a.svg, b.svg, etc., but this is not obligatory)
4. Upload to any font producing website or software - I like [Fontastic](http://fontastic.me/)